# Do different definitions of cut distances on graphs coincide when the graphs have the same set of weighted nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, cut-space

Please refer to Section 2 [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702004.pdf) for notations, and specifically Section 2.3 for definitions of $d_\square$ and $\delta_\square$.

My question is as follows:

> If $G$ and $G^\prime$ are graphs with the same set of nodes and all node weights are the same, then will $\delta_\square(G, G^\prime) = d_\square(G, G^\prime)?$

I believe it should be confirmative, since $\delta_\square$ is a generalization of $d_\square$. However, I cannot prove it based on definitions of $d_\square$ and $\delta_\square$ given in the paper.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It is more reasonable to ask whether $\delta_\square = \widehat \delta_\square$, since both of these allow relabeling nodes. Since $d_\square$ does not allow relabeling nodes, then for a case where $G, G'$ are isomorphic but unequal graphs on the same set of vertices, $\delta_\square(G,G')$ will be positive while $\widehat \delta_\square(G,G')$ and its generalization $\delta_\square$ will be $0$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. Just a small issue: I think there's a typo here. "$\delta_\square(G, G^\prime)$ will be positive..." --> it should be $d_\square(G, G^\prime)$, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant.